# com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException with jpa

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, jpa, persistence

i have question about Hibernate in **JPA** mode.

There is error message:

`com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException`

The requested operation is not supported on forward only result sets.
 When `java.persistence.Query` set `setMaxResults` using by `hibernate` in `JPA`. I need to use `setMaxResults()`.

Comment: The title of this question is less useful than the tags. Surely you can conceive of a more-descriptive title.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure the configuration file and the jar files added for JPA is correctly.